# Render existing component (ref) as route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

### Problem

Our application injects other apps which are rendered using Iframes, the user can access these apps via a tab menu. Obviously the iframe `src` request can take some time, and it is not ideal to perform the request when the user clicks on the tab.

The app should appear as if it is part of our app - i.e. completely seamless and part of our bundle.

---

### What I've Tried - Browser Caching

By simply making a call to the IFrame URL on app load, the browser will cache a majority of the required resources for each app.

To achieve this I created a simple component that renders an IFrame with the required app URL.

```
const PreloadIframe = props =>
  (
      <iframe
        src={props.url}
      ></iframe>
  );
```

I then render this component as **display:none** when the app loads. And when the user clicks on the required tab to load the *real* iframe, the bundle has already been cached and the transition is ***nearly*** seemless.

### Problems with this solution

- The client makes 2 requests to the app URL, once to cache and once again when it should actually be displayed

This cancels out any optimisation that the caching might provide, as the user must still wait on a response from the web service before they can use the injected app.

---

### Ideally

I would like to set the `<PreloadIframe/>` component to **visible** when the user clicks the appropriate tab.

Is it possible to use
[Route.render()](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func) or
[Route.component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component)

To render an existing component, i.e a component that is currently present in the DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating a intermediary component `IframeFactory`

```
class IframeFactory extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.iframeRef.current.setVisible(true);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.iframeRef.current.setVisible(false);
  }
  render() {
    return null;
  }
```

This component takes a ref to an iframe.

Then in my `<Route />` component I simply render this intermdiary component and pass in the appropriate ref.

```
{injectableApps ? injectableApps.map(app => (
        <Route
          key={`/${app.id}`}
          path={`/${app.name}`}
          render={() => (
            <IframeFactory iframeRef={app.iframeRef} />
          )}
        />
      )) : null}
```